# How can I fix "Unknown layer: DenseFeatures" while importing pre-trained keras model?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I was following the tutorial for classifying structured data from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/feature_columns). I trained the model as described with my data which only comprised of numeric data.

I have trained and optimised my model on google colab and downloaded it locally to test it on some new data.

However, when I load the model using this snippet.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("my_model.h5")
```

I get the following error

```
Unknown layer: DenseFeatures
```

...along with the trace.

I have tried setting up `custom_objects` while loading the model like this

```
model = load_model("my_model.h5", custom_objects={'DenseFeatures': tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures})
```

But I still get the following error:

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What could I be doing wrong? I tried going through documentation but couldn't find anything of help on github.